# Splitting a string in Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string in C# the following way:

The Input string is in the form

```
{ Items.Test1 } ~ { Items.test2 } - { Items.Test3 }
```

And I am trying to split it into an array of strings in the form

```
string[0]= "{ Items.Test1 }"
string[1]= " ~ "
string[2]=  "{ Items.test2 }"
string[3]= " - "
string[4]= "{ Items.Test3 }"
```

I was trying to do it in a way such as this

```
string[] result1 = Regex.Matches(par.Text.Trim(), @"\{(.*?)\}").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

It is not working correctly. Showing below results.

```
string[0]="{ Items.Test1 }"
string[1]="{ Items.test2 }"
string[2]="{ Items.Test3 }"
```

pls help me on this

Comment: Are you only looking or regex based solution only?

Comment: No.Any type of solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```cs
Regex.Split(par.Text.Trim(), @"(\s+[~-]\s+)")
```

When splitting with a regex containing a capturing group, the captured texts are also output as part of the resulting array. See the [`Regex.Split` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=net-5.0) expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

The `(\s+[~-]\s+)` pattern captures into Group 1 any one or more whitespaces + `~` or `-` + one or more whitespaces. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Cs%2B%5B%7E-%5D%5Cs%2B%29&i=%7B%20Items.Test1%20%7D%20%7E%20%7B%20Items.test2%20%7D%20-%20%7B%20Items.Test3%20%7D):

[image]

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/dD2Gav):

```cs
var pattern = @"(\s+[~-]\s+)";
var text = "{ Items.Test1 } ~ { Items.test2 } - { Items.Test3 }";
var result = Regex.Split(text, pattern);
// To also remove any empty items if necessary:
//var result = Regex.Split(text, pattern).Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
{ Items.Test1 }
 ~ 
{ Items.test2 }
 - 
{ Items.Test3 }
```

Comment: If I add any word any other character at that time it is not working. Again I have to change the pattern. Like { Items.Test1 } ~ { Items.test2 } - { Items.Test3 } AND { items.test4 } for this result should come 
string[0]= { Items.Test1 }
string[1]= ~
string[2]= { Items.test2 }
string[3]= -
string[4]= { Items.Test3 }
string[5]= AND
string[6]= { items.test4 }

Comment: @SumitManna Correct. There are a lot of ways to improve this regex. 1) `(\s+(?:[~-]|AND)\s+)`. Or, if you need to make sure the matches happen between `}` and `{`, 2) `(?<=})(\s+(?:[~-]|AND)\s+)(?={)`. Another way is to only output the chars/words without whitespaces: 3) `(?<=})\s+([~-]|AND)\s+(?={)`. Please choose your <s>destiny</s>... regex :)

Comment: @SumitManna I tried to аdd а [nоn-regex solution](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69774012/3), but the problem with that one is that the delimiters are not kept. I undеrstаnd string split is much faster, but it would involve much more code that is more еrror-pronе.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex for matching:

```sh
[~-]|{[^}]*}
```

[RegEx Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%7E-%5D%7C%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%7D&i=%7B%20Items.Test1%20%7D%20%7E%20%7B%20Items.test2%20%7D%20-%20%7B%20Items.Test3%20%7D)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[~-]`: Match a `~` or `-`
- `|`: OR
- `{[^}]*}`: Match a `{...}` substring

**Code:**

```
string pattern = @"[~-]|{[^}]*}";
string sentence = "{ Items.Test1 } ~ { Items.test2 } - { Items.Test3 }";
  
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(sentence, pattern))
   Console.WriteLine("Match '{0}' at position {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
```

Comment: If I add any word any other character at that time it is not working. Again I have to change the pattern. Like { Items.Test1 } ~ { Items.test2 } - { Items.Test3 } AND { items.test4 } for this result should come string[0]= { Items.Test1 } string[1]= ~ string[2]= { Items.test2 } string[3]= - string[4]= { Items.Test3 } string[5]= AND string[6]= { items.test4 }

Comment: In that case just add `AND` in alternation like: `pattern = @"[~-]|AND|{[^}]*}"`